# How can I typeset a lowercase circled r (Unicode character U+24E1)?

Tags: symbols, unicode

I would need to typeset in LaTeX the following symbol: ⓡ, which is described here:

https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+24E1

This symbol can be of general use for referring to a randomized order of coauthors in a paper, cf. Ray, D., & Robson, A. (2018). Certified random: A new order for coauthorship. American Economic Review, 108(2), 489-520.

This is not the standard \circledR symbol, but rather something more like \circledr. However, it does not seem to exist in LaTeX.

Could someone help me design this, without having to adopt a font that recognizes this unicode character in LaTeX?

Comment: `\textcircled{r}`? No need for any package.

Comment: Yes, this looks great, thank you very much!